# FastAPI, redis and asyncio.gather – internal server error

Tags: redis, python-asyncio, fastapi

I'm working on a web-project and a few days ago I diagnosed a problem: after restarting the Redis service some urls were throwing a 500 error for multiple requests in a row though Redis was already running.

**env:**

- Python 3.10.10
- Redis 7.0.5
- requirements.txt: redis==4.5.4 aioredis==2.0.1

```
import asyncio
import redis.asyncio as redis
# import aioredis as redis

aioredis_conn = redis.from_url(
    url=f"redis://127.0.0.1:6379",
    decode_responses=True
)
async def main():
    while True:

        print('*******')
        try:
            await aioredis_conn.get('something')
            tasks = []
            tasks.append(aioredis_conn.get('something'))
            tasks.append(aioredis_conn.get('something'))
            tasks.append(aioredis_conn.get('something'))
            tasks.append(aioredis_conn.get('something'))

            results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
            print(f'Gather results: {results}')

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Caught general exception: {e}')

        await asyncio.sleep(3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

**What to do:**

1. Start redis
2. Run script
3. Every 3 seconds you will see

> Gather results: [None, None, None, None]

4. Stop redis and wait for message in terminal

> Caught general exception: Connection closed by server.

If you wait for more than 3 seconds, you will see also

> Caught general exception: Error 61 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. 61.

5. Start redis and in terminal you will see

> Gather results: [None, ConnectionError('Connection closed by server.'), ConnectionError('Connection closed by server.'), ConnectionError('Connection closed by server.')]

On the next iteration of script the result is as expected:

> Gather results: [None, None, None, None]

I don't expect to see exceptions in gather results, and also I'm very confused that these exceptions are from previous loop.

Also I don't see this problem while using aioredis and I assume that the root of the problem is in redis library.

**Am I right and this is a bug. Or am I doing something wrong?**

--

**Steps to reproduce with FastAPI (OLD question):**
Env: Python 3.10, FastAPI 0.95.1, Redis 7.0.5, Docker, requirements.txt: redis==4.5.4

1. Make a request to get 200 OK
2. Stop Redis
3. Make a request to get 500 error
4. Start Redis and wait until it's ready
5. Make 2 requests – you will get 500 error. Exactly 2 times. On third reload it will be 200 OK.

Also, if you remove asyncio.gather OR first await - everything starts working properly.

Why does it work that way?

```
import redis.asyncio as redis

aioredis_conn = redis.from_url(
    url="redis://localhost:6379",
    decode_responses=True,
)

@router.get("/test")
async def test():
    await aioredis_conn.get('anything')
    result = await asyncio.gather(*[aioredis_conn.get('anything'), aioredis_conn.get('anything'), aioredis_conn.get('anything')])

    return {}
```

Error I see in terminal:

```
  File "/project/./vitrina/modules/api/v1/routers/internal.py", line 34, in test
    result = await asyncio.gather(*[aioredis_conn.get('something'), aioredis_conn.get('something'), aioredis_conn.get('something')])
  File "/project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/asyncio/client.py", line 514, in execute_command
    return await conn.retry.call_with_retry(
  File "/project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/asyncio/retry.py", line 62, in call_with_retry
    await fail(error)
  File "/project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/asyncio/client.py", line 501, in _disconnect_raise
    raise error
  File "/project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/asyncio/retry.py", line 59, in call_with_retry
    return await do()
  File "/project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/asyncio/client.py", line 488, in _send_command_parse_response
    return await self.parse_response(conn, command_name, **options)
  File "/project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/asyncio/client.py", line 535, in parse_response
    response = await connection.read_response()
  File "/project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py", line 836, in read_response
    response = await self._parser.read_response(
  File "/project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py", line 256, in read_response
    response = await self._read_response(disable_decoding=disable_decoding)
  File "/project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py", line 266, in _read_response
    raw = await self._readline()
  File "/project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py", line 343, in _readline
    raise ConnectionError(SERVER_CLOSED_CONNECTION_ERROR)
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection closed by server.
```

Comment: What error do you get in the python terminal?

Comment: Sorry I didn't provide that information. I updated question

Comment: Which version of the redis library are you using? Have you tried using a different retry strategy? https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/retry.html

Comment: Redis 7.0.5
I'm not sure that retry will do anything about that error. The problem looks to be in asyncio tasks which created in gather. But I'm not quite sure about that.

Comment: Have you been able to figure it out?